# The Sound After

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> Oh, my beautiful lady first
> There goes away the thirst
> If today were not this blue
> There would be a direct clue
>
> Oh, please look at this mirror
> Then you'll see me no error
> If people called us twins
> Then we will earn some wins
>
> Oh, everything goes around
> The meaningful another round
> But have you just realize
> The people each verse symbolize?

Subtle Hint:

> Though there are 3 verses, they symbolize 4 people in total. Especially, the "lady" is not amongst "us."

Moderate Hint:

> Only 5 words are direct clues, excluding the title.

Decisive Hint:

> They are not actual people, but something similar.

Very Decisive Hint:

> Sound = "ne"

Comment: Not sure how this relates to each line, but is it rot13(Gur sbhe frnfbaf: fhzzre, nhghza, jvagre, fcevat)?

Comment: @Earlien I'm afraid not.

Comment: i don't know enough about the topic to post an answer, but are they rot13(ibpnybvqf?)

Comment: @Bewilderer Correct. Now you should post an answer.

Comment: @DannyuNDos If you are still active, would you mind marking Bewilderer's answer as answer? This riddle is still shown in the list of unanswered questions, but it is essentially answered. Also, Bewilderer deserves the credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The people are

> Vocaloids, computer-animated performers that use recorded voice software to sing

The title refers to

> The last sound of their names, as pointed out in the Very Decisive Hint.

Oh, my beautiful lady first

> This alludes to the fact that vocaloid software is made using the voices of real singers. The first hint references this, since although the singers are involved in the process of creating a vocaloid, they are not regarded as vocaloids themselves.

If today were not this blue
There would be a direct clue

> These lines refer to the most famous vocaloid, Hatsune Miku, who is known for her blue hair and outfit.

Oh, please look at this mirror
Then you'll see me no error
If people called us twins
Then we will earn some wins

> This verse is about two vocaloids: Kagamine Rin and Kagamine Len. They were designed to be "mirror images" of each other, but fans often refer to them as twins instead due to their similar appearance.

Oh, everything goes around
The meaningful another round

> This one I'm not sure about, but this might be Megurine Luka. Her vocaloid software was originally intended to be used as the voice of Hatsune Miku, but was postponed until later, where she became her own character. Her surname in Japanese kanji is 巡音, the first character roughly translating to "round" and the second to "sound".

Comment: Almost perfect. Hint: Consider the meaning of their name. Also you misspelled the rot13(Xntnzvarf)' names.

Comment: I updated my reasoning for number 3, but I have no idea what direction to take your comment in.

Comment: Their surname is written in Kanji, you know.

Comment: Okay, i think i got it now

Answer (score 5):

Are you,

> The Water Cycle.

Oh, my beautiful lady first
There goes away the thirst

> Clouds are made up of water, which they bring down as rain.

If today were not this blue
There would be a direct clue

> If you could not see the "blue" sky, that would means that there is a large about of cloud coverage.

Oh, please look at this mirror
Then you'll see me no error

> This verse refers to rain in the form of liquid water. Water is relfective.

If people called us twins
Then we will earn some wins

> Rain and clouds are both water.

Oh, everything goes around
The meaningful another round

> This line references the water cycle and how it is continuous.

But have you just realize
The people each verse symbolize?

> The first verse references clouds and the second one references rain.

Title

> Clouds and rain are present during thunder storms.

Comment: Ha, I like your answer. Hint: rot13(Gur "crbcyr" ner fvatref.)

Comment: Someone who comes to my mind is Roger Waters From Pink Floyd.